# PDE "factorization"

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

I started by "factorizing" the PDE and while I arrived at a similar form to the 2 linear equation below, there was no "W".

Appreciate any help

Comment: $w$ does not appear out of thin air; it is *defined* to be $u_t-cu_x$.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is adding $c u_{xt}$ to both sides and using the fact that $u_{xt}=u_{tx}$:

$$
\begin{align}
u_{tt} &= c^2 u_{xx} \\
u_{tt} - c u_{tx} &= c^2 u_{xx} - c u_{xt} \\
\partial_{t} (u_t-cu_x) &= c \partial_{x}(cu_x-u_t)
\end{align}
$$

Now if you define $w=u_t-cu_x$, then the above equation gives $w_t=-cw_x$.